# How to get annotations on a map view while clicking a cell in a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, mkmapview

I have  a popoverview containing a tableview,showing some locations. Now my problem is, while clicking on the locations in the tableview i need to go to the view controller containing a  mapview and get annotations . Unfortunately i don't know how to do it, i am new to Xcode. Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

The table view has to notify the view controller in charge of the map about the selection. The most common way to do this is with a `@protocol` and a delegate.

If you do not know how to do this, you should first learn how iOS works. I recommend the excellent and free Stanford University course.